# Create an array of evenly spaced numbers for non-empty cells in row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a process I am trying to code in macros.

For every row in range:

1. I am trying to select non empty cells in a row.
2. For those cells, pick a minimum value `n_1`.
3. Given a multiplication factor `a` create an array (same length as the non empty row) of equally spaced numbers starting with the minimum value, i.e. (`n_k = (a^k)*n_1`).

Something along these lines

```
Dim a As Range, b As Range, number_of_elements as Integer

Set a = Range()

For Each b In a.Rows
    Dim newarray as Variant 'initialize new array

    arr = select_non_empty_cells(b) 'select non empty cells
    number_of_elements = Ubound(arr) 'get number of elements

    ReDim newarray(1 To number_of_elements) As Integer 'set the dimension

    min_val = WorksheetFunction.Min(arr.Value) 'pick minimum value

    For counter = 1 To number_of_elements 'create new array with equally spaced numbers
      newarray(counter) = min_val*1.25^counter 'multiplying factor
    Next counter

    arr.Value = newarray.Value 'set the non empty range to new values
Next
```

And below is what my data will look like. So for the first row I would pick 1033.2 (the minimum value) and create new array of the same length of 5 elements evenly spaced. Same for the second row.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like:

```
Sub Korba()
    Dim i As Long, mini As Long
    Dim WhichRow As Long
    Dim factr As Double

    mini = 3
    factr = 1.25
    WhichRow = 5

    For i = 1 To Columns.Count
        With Cells(WhichRow, i)
            If .Value <> "" Then Exit Sub
            .Value = mini * factr ^ i
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: thats helpful. Thank you. I edited my question to be more detailed about what I am trying to do.